# Conditional REGEX in R to select text in front of or behind a specific character --- "%" in this case

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a character vector of addresses which is formed by merging contents of two different vectors.  A "%" separates the data in each observation, left(1) from right(2).  And the data looks like this:

```
ShippingStreet <- c("123 Main St%234 Center Street", "%555 Folsom Street",
                    "59 Hyde Street%")
```

I want to keep the data on the left side of `%` even if there is something on the right, and on the right side if there is nothing on the left.

So output should look like this:

```
123 Main St
555 Folsom Street
59 Hyde street
```

I wrote a conditional regex as follows and use it in the gsub, but it is not doing what I though it should do.

```
pattrn_pct <- "/(?(?=%)..(%.*$)|(^.*%))/gm"`   <<< looks for % and then selects behind the % to drop if there is something in front of the %, or after the % if nothing in front ...

gsub(pattrn_pct, "", ShippingStreet, perl=T)  <<< replace selection with ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract()` here with the regex pattern `[^%]+`:

```
str_extract(ShippingStreet, "[^%]+")

[1] "123 Main St"       "555 Folsom Street" "59 Hyde Street"
```

**Data:**

```
ShippingStreet <- c("123 Main St%234 Center Street", "%555 Folsom Street",
                    "59 Hyde Street%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` in `base R`

```
sub("^%?([^%]+).*", "\\1", ShippingStreet)
[1] "123 Main St"       "555 Folsom Street" "59 Hyde Street"
```